# Convertir DateTime de formato YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm a String o enteros de corrido ddMMYYYYHH:mm sin espacios

Tags: javascript, java, sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con la columna UserDeviceId, FechaCompleta en SQL Server
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ejecutar mi script

```sql
SELECT UserDeviceId, FechaCompleta  
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] 
WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta) = '2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '01' + CONVERT(nvarchar,(FechaCompleta),112)
```

y tratar de combinar los datos me sale vacío pero si lo ejecuta

Convertir DateTime de formato YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm a String o enteros de corrido ddMMYYYYHH:mm sin espacios el resultado que quiero obtener tiene que ser más o menos así.

10308344020120200653

41906321020120200722

09426559020120200733

.........
....
..
y así sucesivamente

Answer (score 1):

Si estás seguro de que siempre será en el formato indicado, con esto bastará:

```
.select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),103),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),108),':','') as DATE_FORMAT_STRING
```

La consulta anterior te devolverá con segundos, en caso de que no quieras los segundos, solo aplica lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @W_SINSEGUNDOS VARCHAR(13)

select @W_SINSEGUNDOS=replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),103),'/','') 
                    +replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),108),':','')
SELECT SUBSTRING(@W_SINSEGUNDOS,0,13)
```

Comment: todo bien estimado hice la prueba con mi script:
SELECT CONCAT(DAY(u.FechaCompleta) , CASE 
WHEN MONTH(u.FechaCompleta) <10 THEN '0' ELSE MONTH(u.FechaCompleta) end, MONTH(u.FechaCompleta), YEAR(u.FechaCompleta), DATEPART(HOUR,u.FechaCompleta), DATEPART(MINUTE,u.FechaCompleta)) AS DATE_TIME_VARCHAR FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] u WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
pero se come los 0 al ser entero como el dia o el minuto cuando es 01,02,03,04,09

Comment: puedes usar esto que es más simplificado...select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),103),'/','') 
   + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),108),':','') as DATE_FORMAT_STRING

Comment: Al escribir mi consulta el nombre FechaCompleta me subraya con rojo aún estando el nombre de la columna en la tabla "CheckInOut"

DECLARE @W_SINSEGUNDOS VARCHAR(13)
SELECT @W_SINSEGUNDOS=replace(convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') +replace(convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,108),':','') SELECT SUBSTRING(@W_SINSEGUNDOS,0,13) as DATE_FORMAT_STRING FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut]
WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'

Comment: @ElertCordova esta información debe agregarla en su pregunta - presione el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/331399/edit) para editar su pregunta - los comentarios son temporales y pueden ser eliminados.